# Getting infos out of an activex plugin in C#

Tags: c#, .net, streaming, activex, media-player

I'm using the Sopcast activex plugin (sopocx.ocx) in one of my C# applications.
I would like to retrieve the player status ("Buffering the channel", "Playing the channel", "Channel Offline...") and the buffering percentage. Both of these informationss are displayed on the player (I tried to post a picture but I don't have enough reputation yet).

The problem is the Sopcast activex plugin doesn't provide any methods in order to retrieve these informations.

Does someone has any idea on how this could be done??

GetWindowText results in an empty string...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace test
{


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    private void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = sopcast.Handle;
        StringBuilder lpString = new StringBuilder(256);

        GetWindowText(hwnd, lpString, 256);

        MessageBox.Show(lpString.ToString());
    }


    private void playToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sopcast.SetSopAddress("sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/123456789");
        sopcast.SetChannelName("Channel");
        sopcast.Play();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify Id control and get text with api windows

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount); for example

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have tried it. Unfortunately, I got an empty string back. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

here a code sample (replace notepad by your application name) the most important for you is to get from your application a way to get ID control of your ocx window

```
using System;
```

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Text;

using System.Security;

namespace Application

{

```
public class Program

{

    public static void Main ( )

    {

        IntPtr hwnd = UnsafeNativeMethods.FindWindow("Notepad", null);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(256);

        UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(hwnd, stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity);

        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());

    }

}

[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]

internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods

{

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

    internal static extern int GetWindowText ( IntPtr hWnd, [Out] StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount );

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

    internal static extern IntPtr FindWindow ( string lpClassName, string lpWindowName );



}
```

}

Comment: I tried this code sample too but I still get an empty string back [it works fine with "Notepad" though =p]
I added a sample of my code in the original question. You'll see better if I'm doing something wrong (especially about getting the activex control handle ("sopcast")).

Answer (score 0):

I download sopcast and try to get status using spy++:
[image]

As you see, caption is status not the channel...
so you can not get it easier
[image]

the handle you  have catched is for the whole control

Comment: use search tool of spy++ ( visual studio tools) and set the target on the area (control) you are looking for on the desktop

Comment: Edit - Just saw your comment :)

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help a C# newbie!
I don't know why but for me, Caption is always empty for the status (on Spy++). The captions for the Button class are present and I can retrieve them fine with my coding but unlike you, the caption for status is always empty (see here: http://imgcrave.com/u/9X1yz.jpg)
Any ideas on why this is happening??

Comment: you do right, I have only Status on caption, so it is not real value (channel is offline...). Problem is that it is probably a custom control that have no caption property bindable with API.it's under windows 7, 64bits, I have vs2010 ...

Comment: Oh... So, in the end, there is no way to get the real value?

Comment: it will be not easier, but never say never...;-) I try an oakland software activeX inspector but it doesn't give more results

Comment: I'll leave at that for now. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

Sopcast draws the status text using DrawText (i found out using API Monitor http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor). So there is no way of getting the text using conventional GetWindowText function or similar. I was able to obtain the text by hooking DrawText function. For .NET EasyHook will enable you to do this.
My scenario:
I have a winforms app that hosts the activex control and i want to obtain the status text.

```
public class hooklocal : EasyHook.IEntryPoint
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int DrawText(IntPtr hDC, string lpString, int nCount, IntPtr lpRect, uint uFormat);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall,CharSet = CharSet.Auto,SetLastError = true)]
    delegate int DDrawText(IntPtr hDC, string lpString, int nCount, IntPtr lpRect, uint uFormat);

    int DrawTextH(IntPtr hDC, string lpString, int nCount, IntPtr lpRect, uint uFormat)
    {
        //lpString contains the status text 
        return DrawText(hDC, lpString, nCount, lpRect, uFormat);
    }

    public hooklocal()
    {
        try
        {
            var CreateHook = LocalHook.Create(
                 LocalHook.GetProcAddress("user32.dll", "DrawTextW"),
                 new DDrawText(DrawTextH),
                 this);

            CreateHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
        }
        catch (Exception ExtInfo)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }

    }

}
```

To use, instantiate hooklocal class in a new thread at program startup.

EasyHook download
https://easyhook.github.io/downloads.html